# pyodbc ProgrammingError: No results on aws instance but works fine on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

I'm running pyodbc on aws instance with FreeTDS installed. The same code runs fine on my local machine (mac) but runs into  this error: `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.`

Here is the code that I am running.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(
            server="xxx.compute.amazonaws.com",
            database="xxx",
            user='xxx',
            password="xxx",
            port=1433,
            driver=xxx,
            tds_version='7.3',
    )

crsr = conn.cursor()

vol_query = """ SELECT DATE, KEY, VALUE FROM TABLE """

rows = crsr.execute(vol_query1).fetchall()
```

The query doesn't return any results which is expected. On my local machine, `rows=[]` (what I expect) but on the aws instance I see the following error message:

```
 File "/xxx.py", line 129, in yy
    rows = self.crsr.execute(vol_query).fetchall()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I'm using pyodbc 4.0.28 on both machines.

Any ideas what could be the differences? What does `Previous SQL was not a query` mean in this case?

Comment: It means that the SQL statement(s) did not return a row set as the first result. That's usually caused by the SQL command text or stored procedure not calling `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the very beginning. Is your SQL really just a single SELECT statement?

Comment: I also noticed in your code you've assigned the SQL statement to `vol_query` but are calling `execute()` on `vol_query1`; I'm guessing this is just debugging, however, as your error properly references `vol_query`.

Comment: @GordThompson I did try to use SET NOCOUNT ON; on the top of my sql file but it didn't have any effect. This is simplified SQL query. The actual one has multiple sub queries. But why does one machine return `[]` and the other one throws off an exception.

Comment: @FlipperPA you're right. It's a typo. I had written that as an example query. The real query doesn't have that bug. Apparently I can't edit the question to fix that error.